# How to extract all ints within x characters of a word?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Right now I have a CSV file I exported from Outlook and already cleaned up. It is 1 column and each cell contains the body of an email. There's a little over 100 emails/cells. There's a bunch of values I'm looking for like revenue, debt, cash, ebitda. I was wondering if there's away to return a list of all the integers within ~50 characters of the word. For example, if anyone has an idea of how I can return every int within 50 characters of ebitda.

I've tried using regular expressions to find the int that comes after a given word like using "revenue" as the regex to match and then returning the int that follows, but these emails are not written in a consistent manner.

```
numbers_found = []
for cell in email_body:
    match = re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+', cell)
    numbers_found.append(match)
    print(match)
new_df['Numbers found in email bodies'] = pd.Series(numbers_found)

new_df.to_csv('estimateData.csv')
```

Right now, the output is a list of ints found in each email body cell, but there's too many to look through.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample input and a sample output ?

Answer (score 0):

A slice is the way to get a substring in python.

If you want the first 50 characters of a string then `cell[:50]` will give you the first 50 characters of that string.

Here's a link to learn more about slices (see example 6 for index syntax) [Python slice()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice)

---

Also, you should check out the python `csv` module.  It's standard lib and lets you manipulate CSV files fairly easily.

Comment: I think that if you're looking for within 50 characters of a word, you should also look for the word first, then run your regex.  The rule of thumb is "When you use a regex to solve your problem, you've now got two problems".  So, maybe `cell[cell.find('ebitda'):cell.find('ebitda')+50]` would be the slice you're looking for.